# Checking if specific node exists in RSS feed (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have an rss-feed problem that I wonder if you could help me with.

How do I check - with ampscript in an email - if a node exists in an item or not?
If one of the node exists that will be used to populate parts of the email ELSE
the other node/nodes will be used.

Structure of RSS feed is like this

```
<items>
    <item>
        <title>Movietitle</title>
        <prodyear><1976</prodyear>
    </item>
    <item>
        <title>Seriestitle</title>
        <season>3</season>
        <episode>147</episode>
    </item>
</items>
```

So sometimes there is a production year (= movie) and sometimes there is season/eposide number (= series)

I need to populate an email based on this.
I have a lot of other items and all works fine except for this.

Based on this code:

```
%%[

Set @bottom1_prodyears = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/prodyear",1)
Set @bottom1_epis = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/episodenumber",1)
Set @bottom1_seas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/season",1)

if (@bottom1_prodyears == "") OR (isNull(@bottom1_prodyears)) then

    Set @bottom1_epi = Field(Row(@bottom1_epis,1), "Value")
    Set @bottom1_sea = Field(Row(@bottom1_seas,1), "Value")

else then

    set @bottom1_prodyear = Field(Row(@bottom1_prodyears,1), "Value")

endif

]%%
```

But how ever I do this, I end up with it being a series.
So question is:
How do I check - with ampscript - if a node exists in an item or not?

Thanks a lot in advance for any hint.
Best regards /Tove Walden

Comment: Hi Tove, welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to visit the [help] and read [ask]. Please refrain from using the word *urgent* in your posts.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use [**rowCount()**](https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/data-extension/RowCount.html) to check to see if there are results:

```
%%[

Set @bottom1_prodyears = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/prodyear",1)
Set @bottom1_epis = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/episodenumber",1)
Set @bottom1_seas = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml_bott,"//item/season",1)

if rowcount(@bottom1_prodyears) == 0 then

  if rowcount(@bottom1_epis) > 0 and rowcount(@bottom1_seas) > 0 then 

    Set @bottom1_epi = Field(Row(@bottom1_epis,1), "Value")
    Set @bottom1_sea = Field(Row(@bottom1_seas,1), "Value")

  else 

    Set @bottom1_epi = "not found"
    Set @bottom1_sea = "not found"

  endif 

else

    set @bottom1_prodyear = Field(Row(@bottom1_prodyears,1), "Value")

endif

]%%
```

Here's a snip of another method that's a little more fault-tolerant:

```
%%[

set @nodes = BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,"/shipment/items/*",0)
set @rowCount = rowcount(@nodes)

for @i = 1 to @rowCount do

    if rowcount(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("/shipment/items/item[",@i,"]/trackNbr"),0)) > 0 then
      set @trackNbr = Field(Row(BuildRowsetFromXML(@xml,concat("/shipment/items/item[",@i,"]/trackNbr"),0),1),'Value')
    endif

    /* repeat for other fields */

next @i

]%%
```

Answer (score 0):

*OK I know I shouldn't write a comment in an answer like this, but since I am new here I am left with no other choice (I cannot comment with less than 50 in reputation...)
So here we go:*

Thanks you so much for your good reply, however it seems to leave me with the same problem as before, or am I doing something really wrong?

As I do not know what nodes will hold the prodyear OR season/episode,
it doesn't work with just counting the rows.

Say that out of 7 items, there are 2 (somewhere in the feed) holding "prodyear" and (maybe) 5 holding "episode" and "season".
I need to list them all, one after the other.
And IF item number 3 holds prodyear, I need to populate the corresponding table in the email with that information, ELSE I need to populate it with season/episode.

So I need to keep track of what items are what. Movie or series?

So I guess that I somehow will need to loop through all items and find if item 1 is movie or series, if item 2 is movie or series... and so on?

Any idea on how to know what item is what?
Thanks :-)
/Tove